# Speed of sound in non-conformal strongly coupled plasma?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, field-theory, plasma-physics

For a conformal system in (d+1)-dimensions, the speed of sound is given by $ v_{s} = 1/\sqrt{d}$ (for ex : $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM in four dimensions). Is it possible to have a non-conformal strongly coupled plasma system  and still have speed of sound equal to 1/$\sqrt{d}$ ?